# SQL query select only one row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.[PostingID]
      ,[EmployerID]
      ,[JobTitle]                  
      ,pin.[IndustryID]         
FROM [Posting] p
INNER JOIN [City] c
  ON p.CityID = c.CityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostingIndustry pin
  ON p.PostingID = pin.PostingID
WHERE (c.CityID = @CityId OR @CityId IS NULL) 
  AND (p.StateProvinceID = @StateProvinceId OR @StateProvinceId IS NULL) 
  AND (pin.IndustryID = @IndustryId OR @IndustryId IS NULL) 
  AND 
  (
     (p.[Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @Keyword IS NULL) 
     OR (p.[JobTitle] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'  OR @Keyword IS NULL)
  ) 
  AND p.StreetAddress IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.ShowOnMap = 1
```

Which returns results for all the pin.[IndustryID] if IndustryId is not selected or if all the industries are selected. If only one industry is selected I am getting one result which is good, but when one posting is included in multiple industries then I am getting multiple results as on  the image shown below:

[image]

So for example when that's happening I want to get only one result for that posting id otherwise I am getting multiple results for one google map marker per the image below:

[image]

Is there a way how I can optimize the query above to do what I need?

Comment: can you not select the industryID ? Why would the same row have so many same ID's ?

Comment: @briskovich because one posting can have multiple industry id's, it means that one job post can be included in more industries. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about selecting only the row with the smallest IndustryId:

```
SELECT [PostingID]
      ,[EmployerID]
      ,[JobTitle]                  
      ,MIN(pin.[IndustryID])         
FROM [Posting] p
INNER JOIN [City] c
  ON p.CityID = c.CityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostingIndustry pin
  ON p.PostingID = pin.PostingID
WHERE (c.CityID = @CityId OR @CityId IS NULL) 
  AND (p.StateProvinceID = @StateProvinceId OR @StateProvinceId IS NULL) 
  AND (pin.IndustryID = @IndustryId OR @IndustryId IS NULL) 
  AND 
  (
     (p.[Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @Keyword IS NULL) 
     OR (p.[JobTitle] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'  OR @Keyword IS NULL)
  ) 
  AND p.StreetAddress IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.ShowOnMap = 1
GROUP BY [PostingID],[EmployerID],[JobTitle]
```

Whenever you have only one, it returns that one, when you have more than one it returns only the one with the smallest IndustryId.

Comment: top 1 will not work because there might be more results for that state or city but the industry will not be selected. If I do top 1 only one result will be displayed, although the IndustryId is null

Comment: I updated my answer to do a MIN on industryID and group by the remaining columns that are the same. I think it might give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Should be the same yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a group by clause at the end

Use `MAX(IndustryId)`.

Then also

```
GROUP BY PostingId,EmployerId,Jobtitle
```

Comment: Add MAX(IndustryCode) in the SELECT. Sorry im on my phone atm cant copy nice cide blocks

Comment: It should not as Max() will return only the maximum. I see you approved a answer with min and group by.

Answer (score 1):

Don't select industry ID and use "SELECT DISTINCT..."